# Can I add an xAxis break dynamically based on live data feed

Tags: highcharts

I have a live data stream and want to add a break in the xAxis if there is missing data for more than one minute.  Is it possible to dynamically add the break in highstock/highcharts?

I'm adding null values when the feed is missing so chart scrolls, also capturing the time when data feed went missing, when feed comes back I want to collapse the missing data area.  I see examples for adding breaks in the xAxis but all are static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, You can add the breaks by using the chart.update({}); to update the options:

const myBreaks = this.hrchart.options.xAxis[0].breaks;

myBreaks.push({ from: this.missingDataStart, to: data.time, breaksize: 0});

this.hrchart.update({
          xAxis: {
            breaks: myBreaks
          }
        });